# 3D Plot after using for loop and range (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, range

i have some questions for which i couldn't find any answers although i looked up for it.

1. My code so far is the following:

   ```
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
    from matplotlib import cm
    from math import *
    from scipy.special import *
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    ## Definition der Parameter für Druckgleichung nach Rudnicki (1986) ##
    q = 6.0/1000                                                                       
    lameu = 11.2*10**9                              
    lame = 8.4*10**9                               
    pi                                            
    alpha = 0.65                                    
    G = 8.4*10**9                                   
    k = 1.0e-15                                      
    eta = 0.001                                                 
    t = 1000*365*24600        

    kappa = k/eta                                                    
    print "kappa ist:",kappa                                        
    c = ((kappa*(lameu-lame)*(lame+2*G))/((alpha**2)*(lameu+2*G)))  
    print "c ist:",c                                                


    xmin = -10
    xmax = 10
    ymin = -10
    ymax = 10
    for x in range (xmin,xmax):
    for y in range (ymin,ymax):
           r=sqrt(x**2+y**2)
           P=(q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,r**2/(4*c*t)))
           z = P/1e6
           print x,  y,  z


    x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)


    ## Plotting in 3D ##
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0,
                      antialiased=False, vmin=np.nanmin(z), vmax=np.nanmax(z))
    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

    ## Achsenskalen ##
    ax.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)      # x-Achsenskala vorgeben
    ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)      # y-Achsenskala vorgeben

    ## Beschriftung der Achsen ##
    ax.set_title('Druckverteilung')
    ax.set_xlabel('Distanz zu Well [m]')
    ax.set_ylabel('Distanz zu Well [m]')
    ax.set_zlabel('Druck in [MPa]')

    plt.show()
   ```

If i try to run the program, my values for x,y and z show up  as intended, but i dont get any 3D Plot. I had this issue once before, so i tried so define my infinite values for z to be treated as not a number:

```
    z[z==np.inf] = np.nan
```

After adding this to my code, i get the following error:
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment

What exactly means this? I dont get it in the context. I think i need it for my plot?

2. Whats the exact difference in my for loop, e.g. using:

   ```
   for x in range [-10,10]
   ```

   and

   ```
   for x in range (-10,10)
   ```

   ?

I know there are types of functions using

```
    P[x,y]=....
```

instead of only

```
    P=....
```

?

When do i have to use the brackets?

I hope someone can lighten me up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your various questions:

> ```
> z[z==np.inf] = np.nan
> ```
>
> After adding this to my code, i get the following error: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not
>   support item assignment

This is because `z` is just a number, not an array.

The `()` and `[]` confusion is simple, you access elements of a `list` (or any other container class implementing `__getitem__` using the `[]` brackets. You `call` objects using `()`.

Essentially, these two bits of syntax are short forms of the less conveneient versions;

`myObject[key]` results in `myObject.__getitem__(key)`, and `myObject(variable)` results in `myObject.__call__(variable)`. It's just syntax.

Typically, these are used to create functions and container classes (you could misuse them, but it would make for some very confusing code).

As for making your plotting work, you're going to want to make your `z` array of data points, with the correct shape.

The issue you were having is that you did not provide the data to [`plot_surface`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface) as it requires, it needs 2D arrays of data. `XX` and `YY` are just what `numpy.meshgrid` creates, iirc, x and y arguments can just be straight lists, but i haven't tried it.

At any rate, you normally have elements lookign like this (for a square grid):

```
XX
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

YY
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

and then `ZZ` is just the `z` vaules for the function at the corresponding point, i.e. if you're plotting some function, `f(x,y)` then you could do something like:

```
for i in range(len(XX)):
  for j in range(len(XX[0])):
    ZZ[i][j] = f(XX[i][j], YY[i][j])
```

Although there is likely some much faster numpy way to do the array operations that would be faster.

i normally do something like this:

```
import numpy
# other boiler plae variable definitions you have
xs = numpy.linspace(xStart, xStop, num=50)
ys = numpy.linspace(yStart, yStop, num=50)

XX, YY = numpy.meshgrid(xs,ys)
ZZ = numpy.zeros_like(XX)

for i, x in enumerate(xs):
  for j, y in enumerate(ys):
    r=sqrt(x**2+y**2)
    P=(q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,r**2/(4*c*t)))
    ZZ[i][j] = P/1e6

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(XX, YY, ZZ, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0,
                       antialiased=False, vmin=np.nanmin(ZZ), vmax=np.nanmax(ZZ))
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
```

Comment: Thanks so far! I still have troubles to understand your explanation for the last plotting problem. Could you try to explain it in another way? I'm into python just for my thesis, so i only have very basic knowledge of the syntax. Is there another way to code or explain the problem? Do i have to use numpy?

Comment: The last problem as in for `[]` and `()`? or about making the actual plotting work?

Comment: i meant the way u use numpy and np.zeros, in general your last coding example :)